# In Java 8 how do I go from an InputStream to a byte array compressing the stream with zip along the way?

Tags: java, java-8

In other words I have:

```
InputStream inputStream = getInputStreamFromSource();
byte[] output = zipOutputStreamAndConvertToByteArray(inputStream);
```

How would the function `zipOutputStreamAndConvertToByteArray` be implemented?

```
private byte[] zipOutputStreamAndConvertToByteArray(InputStream inputStream)
{
    // what code goes here?
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

Comment: You're assuming the inputstream is zipped which it's not in my case. I'm going from an inputstream to a byte[] and would like to compress the input stream before stuffing it into the byte[] because it's not compressed (and I need the final format to be a byte[]

Comment: Sorry, I meant to link to ZipOutputStream.

Comment: The [`Deflater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) class has a good example in its javadoc.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but it's not working. I'm even stuffing a ByteArrayOutputStream into the ZipOutputStream but the byte array is empty

Comment: @Izruo the link doesn't work

Comment: @StephaneGrenier Yes, somehow the last 'l' got duplicated; I edited it.

Comment: You're also starting with a byte[] and not an inputstream.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier It's not my example, after all. You would have to loop it along with a `inputStream.read(input)`.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier when you ask a question, **post what you have tried**. With 8046 rep points you should know that.

Comment: I tried a dozen different things and nothing worked so I had no idea how far or close I was. I was basically trying to push it into the stream but completely forgot about the ZipEntry code...

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: The problem is that sometimes you really don't know what the code should be. I will admit that input/output streams are my weakness, and as a result I'm not confident on how to move from one to the other. I was trying to stuff a ByteArrayOutputSteam into the ZipOutputStream which was failing, so I was nowhere close. I've also gone through 50+ websites and none of them were very helpful. It was always going the long way, read it all into a byte array, then write the file, re-read it, compress it, etc. Very hacky and terrible.

Comment: Just an FYI for those with negative comments and downvoting the question, one of the higher ranking questions is in exactly this format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string

Comment: @StephaneGrenier don’t use ten year old questions as a guide line for Stackoverflow. The policies have changed over time and a lot of questions accepted back then wouldn’t today. Some of them are even marked as “kept for historical reasons” explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a zip file with file named `file`:

```
private static byte[] zipOutputStreamAndConvertToByteArray(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream)) {
        zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file"));
        try (InputStream in = inputStream) { 
        // this try block can be replaced with IOUtils.copy or ByteStreams.copy
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zip.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
        zip.closeEntry();
    }

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Note that this also creates a ZIP entry in the outputted data. To only compress the data without any overhead a [`DeflaterOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) must be used.

Comment: @Izruo in that case, you can do even better, use [`DeflaterInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/util/zip/DeflaterInputStream.html) to compress right when reading, eliminating the need to deal with `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I’ve added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49727844/2711488) showing the alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Java 9 allows to simplify the solution of [Adam Siemion’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705791/2711488) significantly:

```
private static byte[] zipIntoByteArray(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try(ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream); inputStream) {
        zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file"));
        inputStream.transferTo(zip);
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

The first changes are not Java 9 specific, you can manage both streams with a single `try` statement and you don’t need to close the last (sole) zip entry as it will get closed automatically when the stream is closed. Then, Java 9 allows you to specify an existing variable like `inputStream` without declaring another variable in the `try` statement. Further, you can use [`transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) to transfer all remaining data from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`, without the need to implement a copying routine.

---

As said by Izruo in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705678/in-java-8-how-do-i-go-from-an-inputstream-to-a-byte-array-compressing-the-stream#comment86424922_49705791) when you don’t need the data in the zip file format and only want to hold a single file, you can get rid of the zip file specific overhead by using the `DEFLATE` algorithm directly. We could do this similar to the solution above, just replacing `ZipOutputStream` with `DeflaterOutputStream`, but there’s another alternative, using [`DeflaterInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/util/zip/DeflaterInputStream.html) to compress the data right when reading:

```
private static byte[] compressIntoByteArray(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    try(DeflaterInputStream deflate = new DeflaterInputStream(inputStream)) {
        return deflate.readAllBytes();
    }
}
```

When you have the array containing the compressed data, you can use `new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(array))` to get an `InputStream` decompressing on the fly, replicating the data of the original input stream.

Comment: wait... so you can add `inputStream` to `(ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream); inputStream)`? that is something I was not aware of. nice!

Comment: @Eugene that’s the Java 9 feature, you don’t need a dummy variable, but can just write `try(inputStream) { … }` instead of `try(InputStream dummyVariable = inputStream) { … }`, if `inputStream` is effectively final. This new feature can be combined with the old feature of listing multiple resource in a single `try`. You could also write `try(inputStream; ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream)) { … }` instead.